# SQL Server ordering an Top

Tags: sql, sql-server

In `myTable` is a date and a volume and I want to calculate the average volume of the LATEST 5 TRADING DAYS - not only for the highest date - but for any given `@myDate`.
this works fine:

```
select AVG(volume) 
from 
    (select Top (5) 
        volume, date 
    from 
        myTable 
    where 
        data <= @myDate 
    order by 
        date desc) t
```

I checked it several times and the subselect I used always brings up the latest 5 records before the given `@myDate`.

BUT I AM NOT SO CONFIDENT, maybe it works accidentally because of my indexes.

Here is my question:

- if SQL Server first does the `order by date desc` and THEN picks the `Top (5)` then it will always work fine, in this case I could rely on the results
- But if SQL Sever first picks the `Top (5)` and THEN does the `order by date desc` then I could not rely on the result - my testcases might be working well by accident.

Does SQL Server always first calculate the `order by` and THEN calculate the `Top(5)` ?

Can I rely on this ?

Comment: [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189463.aspx): "When `TOP` is used in conjunction with the `ORDER BY` clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of **ordered** rows" (my emphasis)

Comment: It always does the order by THEN top 5

Comment: many thanks Damien and Jeffrey this is important to know!
I cannot beleive it I get fooled here - asking a most worth while consideration was negatively rated.

Comment: What's annoying here is that, in fairly short order, if you'd searched for `SQL Server TOP` you should have found that page I linked to. So, it seems like rather than expending *any* effort, you instead chose to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you explicitly sort the query with `order by`, the resultset will be sorted, then the first 5 records (in this example) will be returned.

If you do not explicitly sort the query, then sort order is never guaranteed.